# Batch Script To Extract Lines Between Specific Words and re-format the output file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a "test.txt" file in the format of:

```
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
WordA
12
23
45
...
32
12
65
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
WordA
54
76
67
...
68
31
85
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
WordA
89
65
45
...
32
51
75
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
....
```

I want to extract only **the numbers** below each "wordA", re-format data **in a row** with a **2 skip format** and make an output file (like "Output.txt"). It must be noted that the No of lines under each "wordA" with numerical data is fixed (for example 18 lines).

The results should be in this format:

```
12 45 ... 32 65
54 67 ... 68 85
89 45 ... 32 75
....
```

Could anybody help me through? I found the FindRepl.bat, however, I cannot employ what I want. I prefer sth simple and brief.
I have little knowledge of batch script programming and also try writing a nested loops for it, but it does not work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET InFile=Test2.txt
SET OutFile=Output.txt
IF EXIST %OutFile% del /F %OutFile%

FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "wordA" "%InFile%"') DO (
   SET /a first=%%a + 1
   SET /a last=%%a + 18
   SET i=0
   SET ROW=!first!

   FOR /f "skip=!first! delims=" %%b IN (%InFile%) DO (
      if !first! LEQ !last! set Data[!i!]=%%a 
      echo %%b
   )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: I understand you are in a Windows environment. Add that to the tags.

Comment: Do you need to accomplish this using only default Windows tools? Would you consider using a scripting language like Python?, do you have access to text manipulation tools like awk (cygwin)?

Comment: @JosepValls: There is another option (*.exe) but my first priority is writing the code in batch script (*.bat). If it is not possible to write such a code in bat file, please inform me not to waste my time anymore. thanks...

Comment: I also use the FindRepl.bat by: 
@echo off
(
< ACAD-test2.dxf findrepl "AcDbFace" /O:0:+18
)> Output.txt
The results are near to what I want. However, I cannot re-format the data in a row and with a 2 skip step.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET InFile=Test2.txt
SET OutFile=Output.txt

set "i="
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (%InFile%) do (
   if defined i (
      set /A i+=1, odd=i%%2
      if !odd! equ 1 set "line=!line! %%a"
      if !i! equ 18 (
         echo !line:~1!
         set "i="
      )
   ) else if "%%a" equ "WordA" (
      set i=0
      set "line="
   )
)) > %OutFile%
```